# Does my DH table and orientation of the robot correct?

Tags: manipulator, forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

Hello I have a quite interesting 7 dof maniplator. I want to calculate forward kinematics of this robot. I have done a DH table but I am not sure it is correct or not. Can someone please help me?
[image: DH table Calculation]
And also the 3D drawing of the robot is this:
[image: 3D drawing of the robot]